# Custom fonts FMX ios not working Delphi 11

Tags: ios, delphi, fonts

With this Embarcadero tutorial on custom fonts we were enabled to use custom fonts on iOS and Android:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Creating_an_iOS_App#Using_Custom_Fonts_in_iOS_Apps

With new projects we cannot get it to work anymore in iOS, since Delphi 11 (or maybe 10.4). It’s only working on Android.

Does anyone know why the fonts are not picked up/ embedded on iOS?

Comment: It seems I can answer part of the question myself. It depends on the font, some fonts do work on both platforms (iOS Android) and some fonts only on Android. I haven't figured out yet what the difference is but It may have to do with the font style type and file names?

Comment: Note that for Android, using the method in the link the Font > Family value must match the font file name exactly (minus the extension). Any font that you supply _should_ work on iOS, however I have seen reports of some fonts not working. It might be useful to indicate which ones are not

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample application showcasing the use of a custom font on an iOS application. Please, the code is available [**here**](https://gist.github.com/horaciofilho/5323ee7722b10dd595f2ff43c080bdcd). It is important to bring up here the need to add the **custom font file** to the project deployment list:
[image: Picture of the fonts added to the project deployment list in the IDE]

The mentioned sample application contains a combo box to list all the font family names that are available as value for the **TFont.Family** property. I have added the **SCRIPTBL.ttf** font file to the application and it causes the **Script MT Bold** item to be added to the mentioned combo box.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30291654)